# How can you get the icon of an android application (not installed)?

Tags: android

I know how to get the icon of an 'installed' android application BUT I need to retrieve the icon of an application which is not installed (I have the android package name of the app). Does google offer any public service to retrieve this? (I believe Apple does provide that for iOS apps).

Comment: if you have got your answer than accept answer so other can get help from your contribution

Comment: The answer below doesn't answer your question. Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

I have used this code in my project which can help you,How you can get icon follow below code:

```
ImageView imageViewAPK = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView_apk);
File file = new File("/mnt/sdcard/path/to/your/app.apk");
    String sourcePath = file.getPath();

    if (sourcePath.endsWith(".apk")) {
            PackageInfo packageInfo = getPackageManager()
                       .getPackageArchiveInfo(sourcePath, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
            if(packageInfo != null) {
                ApplicationInfo appInfo = packageInfo.applicationInfo;
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 8) {
                    appInfo.sourceDir = sourcePath;
                    appInfo.publicSourceDir = sourcePath;
                }
                Drawable icon = appInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager());
                Bitmap bmpIcon = ((BitmapDrawable) icon).getBitmap();

                imageViewAPK.setImageBitmap(bmpIcon);
            }
        }
```

Comment: is it any API available for this it is working when i have apk file?

Comment: @JigneshM.Mehta  This solution is for APK file which is not installed